# How to connect two meshes together when meshes don't line up

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, vertices

I'm am trying to connect a head model to a body model, but the problem is that the head and body don't line up to where I can just merge the vertices. I tried using a boolean modifier but nothing happened for some reason. I have the head at a certain spot where I want it to connect to the body. Is there any easy way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please add some images to your question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Use the Bridge Edge Loops tool. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops